# How to make anti-clockwise clock

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make an anti clockwise clock using Visual Basic. Please help

Comment: Please consider posting the code you have so far. Here at Stack Overflow the community members enjoy helping others build, fix, or improve their code. However without some code for community members to look at it will be difficult to find assistance on Stack Overflow. Nobody's willing to build a whole program from scratch for a stranger!

Answer (score 3):

[image]

The instructions are here: [Reverse Clock Application](http://www.abovetopsecret.com/forum/thread61591/pg1)

Comment: I could not resist giving a +1 for that! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try building a clockwise clock first and let us know about your progress.